# I cannot found “sdk tools” in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to install LLDB,but I found the "android sdk" is missing in System Setting.

[image]

And I think it should be

[image]

So why "android sdk" is missing in my Android studio? My Android studio version is 2.2.3.
And I clicked the SDK manager icon in the toolbar,it directly open SDK manager window as below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not missing,

1st is the path where your sdk is located in you mac
2nd is for launching sdk manager(Where you can download and delete packages)

I have marked the places in your image

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, how can I see this page? I cannot found "Android SDK" in "System Settings" on my Android studio

Comment: You cannot found in system setting,

Comment: 1st circle is the path where yor sdk is present in system and 2nd is to launch that sdk

Comment: Maybe you dont understand what I mean,please see the first picture in the question.There are "Passwords","Http proxy","Updates","Usage Statistics" under "System Settings",but "Android sdk" is not there. And in your picture,"Android sdk" is under "System Settings"

Comment: I clicked the icon,But it directly goto SDK manager window, I have upload the picture in the question